# Trying to make a play button in html, which can be pressed upon repeatly in order to play a set of notes. (Using Tone.js)

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code in html:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tone"></script>

<button id="tunebtn">Play Notes</button>

<script>
  let synth = new Tone.Synth().toDestination();
  let notes = [
    { note: "C4", duration: "8n" , time: 0},
    { note: "D4", duration: "8n" , time: 0.5},
    { note: "E4", duration: "8n", time: 1}
  ];
  let time = 0;

  const playNotes = () => {
    notes.forEach(note => {
      synth.triggerAttackRelease(note.note, note.duration, note.time);
    });
  };

  document.getElementById("tunebtn").addEventListener("click", playNotes);
</script>
```

I am able to press the button once, in order to play these three notes in the array "note". But when I press it again, the button stops working and nothing gets played. Any idea of what is causing this, and how could this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

YESSS! I found a fix! I checked this link on Github, where someone was having a similar issue: https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js/issues/281

When the code is executed, there is a delay before the first 'triggerAttackRelease' is called. By this time, the scheduled time of 0 for the first note has already passed, and it cannot be scheduled retroactively. As a result, the first note may be abruptly cut short or completely suppressed by the second note.

Using a time constant fixes this issue. Here is my solution:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tone"></script>

<button id="tunebtn">Play Notes</button>

<script>
  let synth = new Tone.Synth().toDestination();
  let notes = [
    { note: "C4", duration: "8n" , time: 0},
    { note: "D4", duration: "8n" , time: 0.5},
    { note: "E4", duration: "8n", time: 1}
  ];


  const playNotes = () => {
    notes.forEach(note => {
        const now = Tone.now()
      synth.triggerAttackRelease(note.note, note.duration, note.time + now);
    });
  };

  document.getElementById("tunebtn").addEventListener("click", playNotes);
</script>
```